# How do I increase the speed an instantiated object spawns in with?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an endless runner game where the player stands stationary on a platform, and objects are instantiated in different patterns further down the platform with an initial speed. I want those objects to increase their speed after a certain time interval is met. For example, if the time interval was 30 seconds and the baseline speed was 10, I would want the speed to go to 20 after 30 seconds have passed, then increase to 30 after another 30 seconds have past, etc. I have a spawner spawning in obstacle patterns with spawn points in various areas.

As of right now, the obstacles spawn in with the same speed no matter what, but increase their speed once they've been spawned in for the duration of the time interval. For example, object 1 is spawned in, moves for 5 seconds at the initial speed, then increases speed, followed by object 2 which does the exact same thing as object 1 upon spawning. Here is my object movement code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ObstacleMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
     public Rigidbody rb;

     // Keeps track of the time and increases speed based off the time
     float time;
     int seconds;
     public int timeInterval; // Time interval where speed is increased

     // Speed stuff
     public Vector3 speedInc; // Speed increase each time interval
     public float initialSpeed; // Initial speed in the Z direction
     Vector3 currentSpeed; // Current speed of the object

     // Vars for locking the object in place so no rotation/sliding occurs
     float startPositionX;
     Quaternion startRotation;

     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         startPositionX = transform.position.x;
         startRotation = transform.rotation;


         currentSpeed = new Vector3(0, 0, initialSpeed);
         rb.velocity = currentSpeed;

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {

         TrackTime();
         if (seconds == timeInterval) {
             currentSpeed = SpeedUp(currentSpeed);
             time = 0;
         }
         rb.velocity = currentSpeed;

         Debug.Log("Speed is: " + currentSpeed);

         LockPos();
     }

     Vector3 SpeedUp(Vector3 iSpeed) {
         Vector3 newSpeed = iSpeed + speedInc;
         Debug.Log("Speeding up");
         return newSpeed;
     }

     void TrackTime() {
         time += Time.deltaTime;
         seconds = (int)time % 60;
         Debug.Log(seconds + " seconds have past");
     }

     void LockPos() {
         Vector3 pos = transform.position;
         pos.x = startPositionX;
         transform.position = pos;
         transform.rotation = startRotation;
     }
}
```

In the code above I am creating a timer, keeping track of the seconds, and then increasing the speed after XXX seconds have passed. What am I doing wrong? I can post the code of the spawner and spawn points if that's necessary. Is there a more appropriate place for this to be executed? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the problem is that your new spawned obstacles do not have the "Game current speed", right?

This is happening cause you're controlling the speed of every obstacles separated from the game state.

So what you do right now is: spawn obstacles always with the same speed, and then every spawned obstacle check if it's his turn to increase the speed.

But what you wan't is to have one object in charge of that spawning and time control, then, when the spawner spawns the obstacle, It assigns the velocity.

Something like:

```
public class ObstacleSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
     // Keeps track of the time and increases speed based off the time
     float time = 0;
     int seconds = 0;
     public int timeInterval; // Time interval where speed is increased

     // Speed stuff
     public Vector3 speedInc; // Speed increase each time interval
     public float initialSpeed; // Initial speed in the Z direction
     Vector3 currentSpeed; // Current speed of the object

     //Prefab of the object
     GameObject obstaclePrefab = null;

     //Tracking all the objects
     List<GameObject> obstacleList = new List<GameObject>();

     void InstantiateNewObstacle()
     {
        GameObject newObstacle = Instantiate(obstaclePrefab);
        newObstacle.GetComponent<RigidBody>().velocity = currentSpeed;
        //If you want to Lock the position (that should not be necessary, do it here too)
        obstacleList.Add(newObstacle);
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {

         TrackTime();
         if (seconds == timeInterval) {
             currentSpeed = SpeedUp(currentSpeed);
             time = 0;
         }
         Debug.Log("Speed is: " + currentSpeed);

         LockPos();
     }

    Vector3 SpeedUp(Vector3 iSpeed) {
         Vector3 newSpeed = iSpeed + speedInc;
         Debug.Log("Speeding up");
         return newSpeed;
     }

     void TrackTime() {
         time += Time.deltaTime;
         seconds = (int)time % 60;
         Debug.Log(seconds + " seconds have past");
     }
}
```

Now every time you want to spawn one new Obstacle you only need to call `ObstacleSpawner.InstantiateNewObject();`. Remember, the `obstacleList` is not necessary but I'm pretty sure that would be useful for your type of game.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I have code for spawn points that are actually doing the instantiating of the obstacles, you're saying that I should be doing all this stuff in the code where they're being created and not their movement code? Also, why is locking their position not necessary? I've found that they rotate slightly as they move down the path so I did kinda a brute force method of keeping them from moving around. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the instantiation of the multiple objects should be done by another entity that have control over the game state (currentSpeed). The movement could be done by each individual obstacle (if needed). I don't know how are your obstacles made off to answer the last question (maybe should be a new one), but if they are static, they shouldn't move by default (maybe they have a rigibody and it's not marked as Kinematic?). Finally, remember to mark this answer as correct (if it is) to help other ones.

Comment: Thanks. I believe that the code is only going to instantiate the object and set the velocity upon it's instantiation. Afterwards, the obstacles slow down and come to a stop. How do I make that a constant velocity/force?

Comment: to make a constant velocity use rigidbody component like rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);